# how Get returnValue from runApex() open cti

Tags: opencti, sforce

in callBack function of runApex(), it reruns JSON...I want to get value from the callback function so that I could perform my logic but I am unable to do so because not having the exact value but a JSON string.

```
sforce.opencti.runApex({
                        apexClass : 'myController',
                        methodName : 'getStatus',
                        methodParams : 'providerClass=' + providerClass,
                        callback : function(result) {
                            if (result.success) {
                                var retVal = result.returnValue;
                                console.log('This is return value >>' , result.returnValue);

                                if( result.returnValue.status == " ringing")
                                {
                                   console.log('This is taking the retun value as ringing');
                                    //set the label to Dialing and dont start the time!
                                }

                            } else {
                                throw new Error('Unable to make a call. Contact your admin.');
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: So is there some problem calling `JSON.parse`? Is this code Javascript?

Comment: if( result.returnValue.status == " ringing") here I want to get the return value which could be (status) ringing
but how can I convert the JSON into JavaScript code and then only get the status however JSON is returning many things...

Comment: can you edit the question and add details about the output from this: `console.log('This is return value >>' , result.returnValue);` What does the payload look like currently?

Comment: it is giving me this value:
{runApex: "{↵  "status" : "ringing"↵}"}

Comment: and if I use onsole.log('This is return value >>' + result.returnValue); then it is returning 
This is return value >>[object Object]

Answer (score 1):

One detail in your question may be critical,  there's an extra space in the string you're comparing:

```
if( result.returnValue.status == " ringing")
```

Per the documentation about [runApex() in the CTI toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_runapex_lex.htm).

The output along with your comment is going to be like so:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "returnValue": {
        "runApex": "{\"status\":\"ringing\"}"
    },
    "errors": null
}
```

Making your javascript to handle the results look like this:

```
sforce.opencti.runApex({
    apexClass : 'myController',
    methodName : 'getStatus',
    methodParams : 'providerClass=' + providerClass,
    callback : function(result) {
        if (result.success) {
            var retVal = result.returnValue;

            var returnJSON = JSON.parse(retVal); // parse the string into an object
            console.log(returnJSON);

            if ( returnJSON.status == "ringing")
            {
               console.log('This is taking the retun value as ringing');
                //set the label to Dialing and dont start the time!
            }

        } else {
            throw new Error('Unable to make a call. Contact your admin.');
        }
    }
});
```